# Function declaration and definition consistency

Tags: c++, declaration, consistency

I have a source that tells me:

> The source file that defines a function should include the header that contains that
>   function’s declaration. That way the compiler will verify that the definition and
>   declaration are consistent.

I'm not sure how this is right, what type of "consistency" are we talking about? Because if the definition and declaration weren't consistent in return type or argument type/number, the compiler would just think I was declaring a separate function and wouldn't verify anything at all.

E.g. If I had a header file test.h:

```
 void func();
```

And a source file testsource.cpp:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "test.h"
 using namespace std;

 void func(int x){
     cout << "Hello StackOverflow" << endl;
 }
```

If I were to run this program the compiler would just think func() and func(int) were different functions and wouldn't throw up a fuss about consistency. What type of consistency is it referring to?

Comment: Overloaded functions.

Comment: C++ supports function overloading, so those two functions `void func()` and `void funct(int)` would be considered two completely separate functions, after their name is mangled

Comment: Use namespaces. `namespace Bob { void f(); }` and then in source `void Bob::f(int x) {}` *won't* compile.

Comment: @Silversonic -- I would not personally have a `header` file for just containing function definitions. The compiler would possibly be fuzzy about not implementing such function

Comment: @Phorce What does that mean? Where would you put the function definitions?

Comment: @NeilKirk Well, in the post the user just gives an example of 1 function.. So I would therefore implement it above main (so the compiler knows where it is) OR have the function definition above main when implementing it below main.. Otherwise, for more functions then I would use a definition `.h` file

Comment: @Phorce I think you've looked too deeply. It's just an example.

Comment: @NeilKirk Well, maybe. I was just pointing out that it was overkill to have one function definition in a header file. It is not a requirement to use a definition file

Comment: In case of classes the compiler would check consistency between member function definition and declaration.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting question.  Your "source" [I assume that's a person or a book, or...] is wrong.   Even though it's a common convention to have function declarations in a header file with the same base name as the file contain the function body, there's no requirement to do so.

Other than, of course, good coding standards.

You are correct, two functions with the same name but different arguments are perfectly acceptable -- as is declaring a function but never defining it (as long as you never call it.)

The C++ compiler does not keep you from shooting yourself in the foot, but good coding practices do.

Now that you edited the quote from the book into the question, I can point out that the quote says "should" not "must".   The common-sense usage is neither mandated nor enforced by the language.  It is simply good programming practice.

Also note that lint-type programs may well detect and complain about this, even though the compiler doesn't.

Comment: *"there's no requirement to do so"* unless you want to call them in another source file.

Comment: It was from C++ Primer, I'll edit in the full quote.

Comment: I am NOT recommending this, but the other source file could declare the method then call it.  The source file where the method is defined does not need to know about the declaration.  As I tried to indicate -- this would be a stupid thing to do, but the C++ language doesn't prevent stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another compilation unit that depends on your `func`, say, a `bar.cpp` defined this way:

```
#include "test.h"

void bar()
{
    func();
}
```

This compilation unit imports your header and the compiler will assume that there will be another object file that defines whatever is declared in that `test.h` header.

Now, if you only had your `testsource.cpp` define a different function, instead (the one with different function signature), the compiler at this stage will complain of a linking error: the symbol `func()` referred to in `bar.cpp` cannot be found anywhere in its link inputs!

Comment: This is irrelevant if source file, which provides function definition, includes header or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Because if the definition and declaration weren't consistent in return type or argument type/number, the compiler would just think I was declaring a separate function ...

This is true. Both in the sense that the compiler would just think this, and in the sense that it could very well be that you are declaring (and defining) a separate function. Perfectly valid as far as the language is concerned.

> ... and wouldn't verify anything at all.

This is not entirely true. There is still something the compiler can verify. While it cannot complain (in your example) that the `func(int)` definition does not match the `func()` declaration, it can complain/warn that the `func(int)` definition does not match **any** declaration.

The goal is to catch mismatches that are likely mistakes. A non-`inline` function with external linkage normally–if good practices are followed–should be declared (in a header) before it is defined (in a source file). If it is not, then there is reason to think the programmer made a mistake. Some compilers can be asked to issue a warning if this happens.

(Since this question is old, I did some digging. While I don't know exactly when this option was added, it was available in gcc 4.4.7, which was released 2012-03-13, three years before this question was asked. So this is a valid answer both now and when the question was asked.)

---

### gcc

For gcc, the option is [`-Wmissing-declarations`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-declarations) (which is not included in `-Wall -Wextra`, possibly because the setup is not wrong, just probably unintended):

> Warn if a global function is defined without a previous declaration. Do so even if the definition itself provides a prototype. Use this option to detect global functions that are not declared in header files. In C, no warnings are issued for functions with previous non-prototype declarations; use `-Wmissing-prototypes` to detect missing prototypes. In C++, no warnings are issued for function templates, or for inline functions, or for functions in anonymous namespaces.

Compiling your example code with this warning enabled gives

> warning: no previous declaration for 'void func(int)' [-Wmissing-declarations]

so you know to double-check your declaration.